# Changing default template in CLion

Tags: project, clion, jetbrains-ide

When I'm creating new C++ library-project in CLion, I'm getting these 3 files:

- library.cpp
- library.h
- CMakeLists.txt

My problem is that I can't change default file extensions and content. For example: library.c++; library.h++

I have changed template settings but it works only when I'm creating a file not a project.

Files configuration:

[image: files configuration]

Include configuration:

[image: include configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it cannot be done. There is 3 years old usability [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8311) for that.